# Customizing Project Designer for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I've created a new project template for Visual Studio 2010, and for this particular project template i want to customize the Project Designer(i.e. the window which opens when you right click your Project and Click on the Properties Option).

How can I customize the Project Designer programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't get your question correctly But,
try this it will help you,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173496/How-to-Create-a-Visual-Studio-Add-in-that-Launches